# How to clone VirtualBox VM?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, clone

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and need to clone a VirtualBox VM of Windows XP Pro. How do you do this on Windows 7?

Comment: I also found this Windows-only program that is quite nifty: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22422l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-clone-virtualbox-virtual-machine.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not handy when you just need to clone it to one place, but if you are say making a development VM for a team I just exported by vm as a virtual appliance.

At the VirtualBox screen File -> Export Appliance then go to your other computer and File -> Import Appliance.